# Controller HttpServletRequest locale does not change

Tags: java, spring, controller, request, locale

When I change preferred language via request parameter the language changes in the web pages (messages are retrieved with `<spring:message code="xxxx"/>`) but locale does not change in the controllers, for example:

```
private void simpleControllerMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelAndView model) {
        System.out.println(request.getLocale().toString()); // prints default application locale no matter what
    }
```

dispather-servlet.xml contains:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>messages</value>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="lt" />
    <property name="cookieName" value="lang" />
    <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"/>
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>  
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
          <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Why locale does not change for HttpServletRequest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HttpServletRequest.getLocale() doesn't give you current locale. It gives you the preferred (preferred by the browser -judging from the header). 
If you want to get current locale you have to pass the Locale through method parameter:

```
private void simpleControllerMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelAndView model,Locale locale) {
    System.out.println(locale);
}
```

or just get Locale from static holder:
LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()

Comment: Unexpected behaviour of `HttpServletRequest.getLocale()` on one hand, failure to read what does the method exactly do on the other hand. Thanks for the answer.